# How to set a C# variable value from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm making an ajax request and storing my response in an hidden field.I'm doing this through javascript using getelementbyid.value.This javascript function is on body onload.Now after I get this value I would like to use this in C#.I can't have any button onclick event or anything of that sort.Just have a hidden input type

Comment: As per my understanding u cant use script variable on server side. Also can u put some piece of code here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an asp.net HidenField webControl has a value then all you need to do is the following:

aspx page:

```
        <asp:hiddenfield id="hf_MyValue"
          value="whatever" 
          runat="server"/>
```

cs page:

```
string value = hf_MyValue.Value;
```

If you want to do something with the value when it's assigned handle the onValueChanged event:

```
        <asp:hiddenfield id="hf_MyValue"
          onvaluechanged="ValueHiddenField_ValueChanged"
          value="whatever" 
          runat="server"/>
```

While you CAN use a value of an asp.net HiddenField that is set using javascript in C# make sure that you understand that this can only be done after a postback.

[Here is some info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) on the Client/Server relationship.  Javascript and C# respectively in your question.

Comment: Can you tell me how to postback for hidden field.I tried and it's not working